Huge performance degradation after upgrade to Postgres 16
Heroku updated my Postgres instance from version 13 to 16 tonight.
After this update we have huge performance issues. The simplest queries take a few seconds to execute.
Regardless of whether I do it through an application or manually through an IDE/DBeaver.
Has anyone had a similar problem?

Run Analyze on the databases. At here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html see step 17 Statistics.

After ANALYZE, check the query plans using explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for the slow statements.

According to this Deprecations there should not have been a forced upgrade from 14 --> 16 yet. Are you sure it was not version 13. If not then this is something you should bring up with Heroku.

@AdrianKlaver you're right. Of course it was version 13 that was marked as Deprecated.

I fixed this problem. I must REINDEX all schemas.

Please post the resolution as an answer so that the question no longer appears in searches for unanswered questioned. It is completely acceptable to answer one's own question.

I fixed this problem. I must REINDEX all schemas.
